# How can i use hooks in functional component when adding React to a Website?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to use a useEffect, useState and other hooks in a react website not built with node. How can i do these following below:

`1.How can i use a functional component when adding React to a Website?`

`2. How can i use hooks in functional component when adding React to a Website?`

I don't want to use class based component as referenced here https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Answer (score 0):

An example of a functional component:

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

and how it is called in another functional component:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Welcome name="Sara" />
      <Welcome name="Cahal" />
      <Welcome name="Edite" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

For hooks, the most used hook that you will start with is useState hook.

You need to import it first:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

and use it inside you component to create and change the value of a variable.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

`count` is a variable that is called state. `setCount` is how you update that state, and `0` is the default assigned value.

Comment: Please follow this documentation to avoid dealing with class components https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: @Oussana import React, { useState } from 'react'; will not work. Remember i said i'm not using react app (react with node). I adding react to an existing html page  https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html